# Confused with OR (|) oparator

Tags: c

I understood the code except for this `c|mask` part. So can someone help me to understand what is happening in  `c|mask`. Is it like this, `char|int`? and the output of this conditional operation is `int`?

```
int main() {
    char c=48;
    int i, mask=01;
    for(i=1; i<=5; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", c|mask);
        mask = mask<<1;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

by the way this code works. and outputs: 12480

EDIT: I have no question about the code. I just want to know about the "char is promoted to int" (`c|mask`). How it is done and why and can it be vice versa? -thanks

Comment: The char gets promoted to int followed by the *binary or*.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? What did you do to find out yourself (what did e.g. google show up when you search for "C or operator"?

Comment: he doesn't understand why and how it works, and he asked here to find out. just a wild guess...

Comment: It might be helpful to print the values as int instead of char.

Comment: @Shark. you are right. I don't understand how it works and why it is added in this code.

Comment: can any data type gets promoted to int by using this | operator like this?

Comment: can it be vice versa? like int is converted to char or float or double?

Comment: @Shark: (If that comment was for me, you should learn to address a comment properly. I just saw it by chance) I don't think that is the reason. OP just thinks someone explaining basic programming things is easier than a simple search and reading a more general text which requires understanding abstractions. Problem is, a C book will provide the whole picture, any answer here by its nature just a small view. I'm afraid her next question will be what if he uses `long` instead of `char`.

Comment: @Olaf don't worry, i know how to direct comments. I just didn't think it was worthy enough and played a chancecard that "if you return, you might see it; otherwise it's no big deal".
@Gilweed: promotion isn't quite the same as casting (even though they work similarly). an `int` can never be promoted to `char`.

Answer (score 4):

Smaller integer types like char get promoted to `int` on many operations, including `|`, but that promotion isn't really relevant here. `|` is the [binary or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) operation, where each bit in the result is set if at least one of the corresponding input bits is set. `c|mask` is an integer, but `printf("%c"` prints it as a character. To print it as an integer, you would use `printf("%d"` instead. `c = 48` represents the ASCII digit `'0'` with the other digits following right after it.

```
c = 48 = 0x30 = '0'
```

Evaluating it for each iteration:

```
i = 1, mask =  1 = 0x01, c|mask = 0x31 = '1'
i = 2, mask =  2 = 0x02, c|mask = 0x32 = '2'
i = 3, mask =  4 = 0x04, c|mask = 0x34 = '4'
i = 4, mask =  8 = 0x08, c|mask = 0x38 = '8'
i = 5, mask = 16 = 0x10, c|mask = 0x30 = '0' (the mask bit is already set in `c`, so the result is 'c' without changes)
```

Comment: What's the function of the `mask`?

Comment: @zhenguoli The single set bit moves one to the left on each iteration, so it takes on the powers-of-two from 1 to 16.

Comment: But why the `c` bit or `mask` and take the loop? Does he want to get the character representation of the low 4 bits of the `mask`?